# Is it possible to do a full image backup of an android 11 phone?

Tags: backup, images

Most manufacturers require a factory reset before sending away to be repaired. However if it's not a software fault then you are inconvenienced.

Is it possible to do a full image backup of the phone? I've read through a few of the answers here but they're a few years old.

Comment: depends on phone

Comment: If an app uses the hardware based `AndroidKeyStore` then it is not possible. As far as I know cryptographic keys in that store can only be accessed/used but not exported even with root permissions (if the key has been created as non-exportable key). If you perform a factory reset the necessary keys to decrypt those keys are gone.

Comment: D2D transfer apps are used to backup nowadays. I am not quite sure but this solution might use the same underlying technique https://www.xda-developers.com/lineageos-seedvault-open-source-backup-solution

Answer (score 0):

So let's create a new fresh answer then. As mentioned in another answers [[1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/104856/392080)] [[2](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/159860/392080)] one can do a full backup of

- boot
- system
- data (there is [a trick](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/how-to-backup-your-internal-storage-through-a-twrp-backup/64010) to include the Internal Storage)

by booting into TWRP and doing so called NANDroid backup (IDK, it's just a big "Backup" button on the main screen)

Once you [find a TWRP image](https://twrp.me/Devices/) for your device, the process looks like this.

```
adb reboot bootloader

# when device at the booloader screen
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img

# be ready to press a key combo
fastboot reboot
```

Before the tablet/phone boots up hold **Volume Down + Power** buttons. This way we end up in the same bootloader, select **Recovery Mode** and it will load TWRP.

For more details read [here](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/how-to-backup-your-internal-storage-through-a-twrp-backup/64010)

[image]